# Specifying command line options to protogen from inside the IDE?

Tags: protobuf-net

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I wonder if there is a way to specify -p:detectMissing when running the ProtoBufTool custom tool. Found nothing on the web about it. Do I have to stick to calling protogen from the command prompt (or wrap protogen inside my own batch file) if I need to specify command line options?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a ... er, *hack*. The "custom namespace" is the only thing available to me. This is still usable to supply a namespace, so I choose to accept semi-colon delimited options after that. So if you don't want to specify the namespace, the first character **must** be a semi-colon. So; try setting:

```
;detectMissing
```

as the "custom namespace" (properties pane of the .proto file)

Comment: I've been away for a while, but I'm back now. Tried the Custom Tool Namespace trick and it works. Thanks a lot!